# Share same variable value in attributes of package.json and tsconfig.json

Tags: npm, package.json

In `tsconfig.json` I define the property `outdir`, for instance like this

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    ....
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "my-outdir"
     }
}
```

Now, I need to use the same value, `my-outdir`, in some `scripts` of `package.json`.

What I have been able to do so far is to define a *custom* property in my `package.json` where I store the value `my-outdir` and reference it in the scripts section, like this

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "version": "npm run tsc && git add -A ${npm_package_my_app_outdir}",
        ...
    }
    "my_app": {
        "outdir": "my-outdir"
    }
}
```

What I am missing though is a way to reference the same value in `tsconfig.json`. Is there a way to have only one place where I define the value `my-outdir` and reference it both in `tsconfig.json` and `package.json`?

Comment: You actually only use it for one thing in what you're showing, just provide it in two different ways.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My goal is to make sure that if someone runs directly the `tsc` command without using the npm script ends up using the same `outDir`. This is why I would like to have the name of the `outDir` defined only in one place for both package.json and tsconfig.json

Comment: That feels like a them problem but OK, have the one place be the tsconfig, then it's not needed in the package file. Why _are_ you overriding it from the script?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I used the wrong example. The script where I have to duplicate the `outDir` info is this one `"version": "npm run tsc && git add -A ${npm_package_my_app_outdir}"`. I have updated also the question.